# How to execute a function on mouse click on rectangle HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I'm looking for a simple way to execute a function when someone clicks on a rectangle inside an HTML5 Canvas. I would like to do it in a way that doesn't require any special libraries. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a no-library way which involves:

1. Listening for mousedown events:

   ```
   var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");

   canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;
   ```
2. Testing if the clicked mouse position is inside the rectangle:

   ```
   var rect={x:100,y:100,w:75,h:40};

   // mx & my are the mouse coordinates
   if(mx>=rect.x && mx<=rect.x+rect.w && my>=rect.y && my<=rect.y+rect.h){
           alert("clicked in rect");
   }
   ```

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var BB,BBoffsetX,BBoffsetY;
setBB();

var rect={x:100,y:100,w:75,h:40};

ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.w,rect.h);


canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;

function handleMousedown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var mx=e.clientX-BBoffsetX;
  var my=e.clientY-BBoffsetY;
  if(mx>=rect.x && mx<=rect.x+rect.w && my>=rect.y && my<=rect.y+rect.h){
    alert("clicked in rect");
  }
}

function setBB(){
  BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  BBoffsetX=BB.left;
  BBoffsetY=BB.top;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Click in the rect for an alert</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me a little while to figure out how it worked, and adapt it to fit into my current code, but it works and turned out to be much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you!

Comment: Interestingly, this answer doesn't account for the scroll position, so it doesn't work when the page has been scrolled (ie. in the code snippet, if you scroll the frame down and try again it won't work).  I'm working on making a similar fix that accounts for this though.

Comment: How would you get this code to work if the rectangle on the canvas was rotated by say 45 degrees?